# regex101: How can I capture the street address on each line in a more economical way? I am new to Regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture the street on each line of text on the regex101.com, but the
address on line 2; "4241 Jerry Dove Drive" and line 6; "946 Douglas Dairy Road" are
giving me problems because they are the only 3 word street names. There must be a better way of writing this!

expression:

```
\s(\d{2,4}\s[A-Z]\w*\s[A-Z]\w*\sD?r?i?v?e?R?o?a?d?)
```

This is the txt file:

```
Jazmine Holcomb 3212 Adams Avenue Washington MD eluir.azevedo.7o@lucidmode.com
Sofie Hagan 4241 Jerry Dove Drive Erie PA zfraction00t@jfaccupuncture.com
Cairo Tyson 3768 Clifford Street San_Jose CA varifi.amin@disabilitylawyersatlanta.com
Tasmin Kearney 2956 Adams Drive El_Campo CA 1paul.clinssonq@aprilmovo.com
Aydin Moran 3727 Sarah Drive Lake_Charles LA 3egdol@blogspot.miami
Samirah Pollard 946 Douglas Dairy Road Prosperity SC rzekohahaha@gmailup.com
Jaskaran Wheeler 1521 Richards Avenue Torrance CA ardit.ditty@netfacc.com
Gerrard Browning 4690 Felosa Drive Los_Angeles CA cgbeshar@lotomoneymaker.com
Haleema Craft 73 Pinchalone Street Norfolk VA 0kjhdsxz123e@summitgg.com
Brett Neal 4079 Johnson Street Garner NC fali_gx2000w@plussmail.com
```

Comment: Can you describe an unambiguous way to recognize the street part of an address? If you can't define it clearly, you can't write a regexp for it.

Comment: Try working backwards from the end of the line. The city, state, and email are each single words. So match those at the end, match the name at the beginning, and everything in between is the street address.

Comment: Why `D?r?i?v?e?R?o?a?d?`? That will match any mixture of the letters., like `DRad`. If you want to match different types of streets, use `(Drive|Road|Avenue|Street)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex could suit you:

```
\s(\d{2,4}(?:\s[A-Z]\w*){1,3}\s(?:Street|Drive|Avenue|Road))
```

It contains a non-capturing group `(?: )` for the words before the final word, and says have 1 to 3 of such words, and then as last word it needs one of

- Street
- Drive
- Avenue
- Road

You need to enclose that last word in a non-capturing group as well, otherwise, the first variant would be the 1 to 3 words + "Street" and the other variants would be just "Drive", "Avenue" or "Road" without the words before.

If you like, you could increase the number of words before the final word by any number, or up to infinity by just having a `+` (one or more) instead of the `{1,3}` (any number between 1 and 3)

Comment: Didn't even cover what non-capture groups were, looking into it now thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Possible (quick) solution is the following:

```
import re

string = """Jazmine Holcomb 3212 Adams Avenue Washington MD eluir.azevedo.7o@lucidmode.com
Sofie Hagan 4241 Jerry Dove Drive Erie PA zfraction00t@jfaccupuncture.com
Cairo Tyson 3768 Clifford Street San_Jose CA varifi.amin@disabilitylawyersatlanta.com
Tasmin Kearney 2956 Adams Drive El_Campo CA 1paul.clinssonq@aprilmovo.com
Aydin Moran 3727 Sarah Drive Lake_Charles LA 3egdol@blogspot.miami
Samirah Pollard 946 Douglas Dairy Road Prosperity SC rzekohahaha@gmailup.com
Jaskaran Wheeler 1521 Richards Avenue Torrance CA ardit.ditty@netfacc.com
Gerrard Browning 4690 Felosa Drive Los_Angeles CA cgbeshar@lotomoneymaker.com
Haleema Craft 73 Pinchalone Street Norfolk VA 0kjhdsxz123e@summitgg.com
Brett Neal 4079 Johnson Street Garner NC fali_gx2000w@plussmail.com"""


re_pattern = re.compile("(\d+\s[a-z\s]+(?:Avenue|Drive|Street|Road))", re.I)

found = re_pattern.findall(string)

print(found)
```

Prints

```
['3212 Adams Avenue',
 '4241 Jerry Dove Drive',
 '3768 Clifford Street',
 '2956 Adams Drive',
 '3727 Sarah Drive',
 '946 Douglas Dairy Road',
 '1521 Richards Avenue',
 '4690 Felosa Drive',
 '73 Pinchalone Street',
 '4079 Johnson Street']
```

Regex explanation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
\d+ [\w ]*?(?= \w+ \b[A-Z]{2}\b)
```

It says

- Some numbers
- Followed by a space
- Followed by letters and spaces until
- An ignored group starting with a space, a word, a space and exactly two capital letters